# How to get the connected graph between 2 resources in RDF Graph

Tags: sparql, rdf, semantic-web

In an RDF Graph, Given 2 nodes, one property node and other subject node, I want to construct all the triples connected to them. How can I construct them? It should be general, not only particularly for the graph given.

Example if `A1` and `d` is given, these triples have to be constructed

```
:A1 :a :B1, 
:B1 :b :S1,
:B1 :b :S2,
:S1 :d :D1,
:S2 :d :D2,
```

[image: RDF Graph]

Comment: At first glance this problem seems *very* similar to the one in your earlier question (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37186530/how-do-i-construct-get-the-whole-sub-graph-from-a-given-resource-in-rdf-graph ) - the only difference being that in this case you have a start _and_ end point. Have you tried adapting the solution given in that question to this case, and if so, why didn't that work? You can [edit] your question to add more details about what you've tried sofar and where you're stuck.

Comment: I agree with @Jeen_Broekstra, it's almost the same and should be possible by extending the answer of his previous question.

Comment: Moreover, the expression "property node" is somehow misleading in RDF, as properties are usually considered to be edges in the graph.

Comment: This is answered in your previous question.  I also extended my answer there to include the more specific case that you've described here.