# How to return all S->P->O triples from a starting resource to a specified path depth?

Tags: sparql, virtuoso

My goal is to graphically represent the S->P->O relations within a depth two edges from the specified resource, `p:Person_1`. I want all relations within that path length to be returned from my query as `?s, ?p, ?o` for further processing in my graphical application.

I tried the first query below which gives me my first set of `?s ?p ?o` with repeats, then `?p2, ?o2, ?p3, ?o3` as additional columns in the result. I want to bind `?p2` and `?p3` to `?p`, `?o2` and `?o3` to `?o`.

```
  SELECT *
    WHERE {
        p:Person_1 ?p ?o .
        BIND("p:Person_1" as ?s)
        OPTIONAL{
            ?o ?p2 ?o2 .
        }
        OPTIONAL{
            ?o2 ?p3 ?o3 .
        }
    }
```

Then, based on [How do I construct get the whole sub graph from a given resource in RDF Graph?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37186530/how-do-i-construct-get-the-whole-sub-graph-from-a-given-resource-in-rdf-graph), I tried using `CONSTRUCT` to return the graph.

```
PREFIX p: <http://www.example.org/person/> 
PREFIX x: <example.org/foo/>

construct { ?s ?p ?o }
FROM <http://localhost:8890/MYGRAPH>
where { p:Person_1 (x:|!x:)* ?s . 
        ?s ?p ?o . 
}
```

I am using Virtuoso and I get the error:

```
Virtuoso 37000 Error SP031: SPARQL compiler: Variable ?_::trans_subj_9_3 in T_IN list is not a value from some triple
```

I could post-process the result from my first query but I want to learn how to do this correctly with SPARQL, preferably on Virtuoso.

Update after testing the advice from @AKSW : 
Both `CONSTRUCT` and `SELECT` statements work with the pattern suggested.

```
CONSTRUCT { ?s ?p ?o }
FROM <http://localhost:8890/MYGRAPH>
where { p:Person_1 (x:foo|!x:bar)* ?s . 
        ?s ?p ?o . 
} LIMIT 100
```

and:

```
SELECT s ?p ?o 
FROM <http://localhost:8890/MYGRAPH>
where { p:Person_1 (x:foo|!x:bar)* ?s . 
        ?s ?p ?o . 
} LIMIT 100
```

The `SELECT` results in several duplicates that cannot be removed using `DISTINCT`, which results in an error that I assume is due to the 'datatype' of some of the returned values.

```
Virtuoso 22023 Error SR066: Unsupported case in CONVERT (DATETIME -> IRI_ID)
```

It appears some post-SPARQL processing is in order.

This gets me most of the way there. Still hoping I can find a solution for SPARQL that is like Cypher's "number of hops away" :

```
OPTIONAL MATCH path=s-[*1..3]-(o)
```

Comment: Virtuoso has some bugs with property paths, and this "wildcard pattern" (variables are not allowed) does not work. I already raised in issue on Github, see https://github.com/openlink/virtuoso-opensource/issues/514 You can try to use something like `(x:foo|!x:bar)*` given that both properties don't exist.

Comment: One comment, property paths are really tricky, especially for the people that have to implement it in an efficient manner. And your query, well  could lead to a lot of joins and return the whole graph in the worst case.

Comment: Your suggestion of (x:foo|!x:bar)* works with both CONSTRUCT and SELECT. I will update my original post with this information.  Adding a LIMIT is likely a good idea.  I am disappointed to not find a option like Cypher's ability to specify the number of "hops" , like:    OPTIONAL MATCH path=s-[*1..3]-(o)

Comment: It's worth noting that virtuoso does support the notation that appeared in property path drafts but didn't make it into the final spec.  You can do,  e.g., `?s :p{n,m} ?o` to find paths of length n to make between ?s and ?p.

Comment: This looks like the documentation I am looking for on property paths. https://www.w3.org/TR/sparql11-property-paths/    (thanks to K. Idehen via Twitter)

Answer (score 1):

Here is a SPARQL query that works in Virtuoso. Note the SPARQL W3C standard does not support this syntax and it will fail in other triplestores.

```
PREFIX p: <http://www.example.org/person/> 
PREFIX x: <example.org/foo/>
# CONSTRUCT {?s ?p ?o}  # If you wish to return the graph
SELECT ?s ?p ?o   # To return the triples
FROM <http://localhost:8890/MYGRAPH>
where { p:Person_1 (x:foo|!x:bar){1,3} ?s  .
  ?s ?p ?o .
}LIMIT 100
```

See also K. Idehen's wiki entry here:  http://linkedwiki.com/exampleView.php?ex_id=141

And thanks to @Joshua Taylor for advice in the same area.

Answer (score 0):

[Working Drafts of SPARQL 1.1 Property Paths](http://www.w3.org/TR/2010/WD-sparql11-property-paths-20100126/) included the `{n,m}` operator for handling this issue, which was implemented (and will remain supported) in Virtuoso. Here's a tweak to @tim's response.

> [image: screencap of SPARQL 1.1 draft]

- Live [SPARQL Query Results Page](http://dbpedia.org/sparql?default-graph-uri=http%3A%2F%2Fdbpedia.org&query=PREFIX%20rdf%3A%20%3Chttp%3A%2F%2Fwww.w3.org%2F1999%2F02%2F22-rdf-syntax-ns%23%3E%20%0D%0ASELECT%20DISTINCT%20%3Fs%20as%20%3FEntity%20%3Fo%20as%20%3FCategory%20%0D%0AWHERE%20%7B%20%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%3Fs%20a%20%3Chttp%3A%2F%2Fdbpedia.org%2Fontology%2FAcademicJournal%3E%20%3B%20%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20rdf%3Atype%7B1%2C3%7D%20%3Fo%20%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%7D%20%0D%0A%0D%0ALIMIT%20100&format=text%2Fhtml&CXML_redir_for_subjs=121&CXML_redir_for_hrefs=&timeout=30000&debug=on) using the DBpedia endpoint (which is a Virtuoso instance).
- Live [SPARQL Query Definition Page](http://dbpedia.org/sparql?default-graph-uri=http%3A%2F%2Fdbpedia.org&qtxt=PREFIX%20rdf%3A%20%3Chttp%3A%2F%2Fwww.w3.org%2F1999%2F02%2F22-rdf-syntax-ns%23%3E%20%0D%0ASELECT%20DISTINCT%20%3Fs%20as%20%3FEntity%20%3Fo%20as%20%3FCategory%20%0D%0AWHERE%20%7B%20%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%3Fs%20a%20%3Chttp%3A%2F%2Fdbpedia.org%2Fontology%2FAcademicJournal%3E%20%3B%20%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20rdf%3Atype%7B1%2C3%7D%20%3Fo%20%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%7D%20%0D%0A%0D%0ALIMIT%20100&format=text%2Fhtml&CXML_redir_for_subjs=121&CXML_redir_for_hrefs=&timeout=30000&debug=on) that opens up query source code in the default DBpedia query editor.
- Actual Query Example:

  ```
  PREFIX rdf: <http://www.w3.org/1999/02/22-rdf-syntax-ns#> 
  SELECT DISTINCT ?s AS ?Entity 
                  ?o AS ?Category 
  WHERE { 
          ?s  rdf:type       <http://dbpedia.org/ontology/AcademicJournal> ; 
              rdf:type{1,3}  ?o 
        } 
  LIMIT 100
  ```

Answer (score 0):

Bearing in mind that the `r{n,m}` operator was deprecated in the [final SPARQL 1.1](https://www.w3.org/TR/sparql11-query/#propertypaths) (but will remain supported in Virtuoso), you can use `r/r?/r?` instead of `r{1,3}`, if you want to work strictly off the current spec:

```
PREFIX rdf: <http://www.w3.org/1999/02/22-rdf-syntax-ns#> 
SELECT DISTINCT ?s AS ?Entity 
                ?o AS ?Category 
WHERE { 
        ?s  rdf:type                          <http://dbpedia.org/ontology/AcademicJournal> ; 
            rdf:type / rdf:type? / rdf:type?  ?o 
       }
LIMIT 100
```

> [image: screencap of SPARQL 1.1 Property Path spec]

Here's a [live example](http://dbpedia.org/sparql?default-graph-uri=http%3A%2F%2Fdbpedia.org&query=PREFIX+rdf%3A+%3Chttp%3A%2F%2Fwww.w3.org%2F1999%2F02%2F22-rdf-syntax-ns%23%3E+%0D%0ASELECT+DISTINCT+%3Fs+AS+%3FEntity+%0D%0A++++++++++++++++%3Fo+AS+%3FCategory+%0D%0AWHERE+%7B+%0D%0A++++++++%3Fs++rdf%3Atype++++++++++++++++++++++++++%3Chttp%3A%2F%2Fdbpedia.org%2Fontology%2FAcademicJournal%3E+%3B+%0D%0A++++++++++++rdf%3Atype+%2F+rdf%3Atype%3F+%2F+rdf%3Atype%3F++%3Fo+%0D%0A+++++++%7D+++++%0D%0ALIMIT+100&format=text%2Fhtml&CXML_redir_for_subjs=121&CXML_redir_for_hrefs=&timeout=30000&debug=on), against the DBpedia instance hosted in Virtuoso.

Answer (score 0):

Should you be looking for LinkedIn-like presentation of Contact Networks and Degrees of Separation between individuals, here is an example using Virtuoso-specific SPARQL Extensions that solve this particular issue:

```
SELECT ?o                                              AS ?WebID
       ((SELECT COUNT (*) WHERE {?o foaf:knows ?xx}))  AS ?contact_network_size
       ?dist                                           AS ?DegreeOfSeparation 
       <http://www.w3.org/People/Berners-Lee/card#i>   AS ?knowee
  WHERE
    {
      {
        SELECT ?s ?o
        WHERE
          {
            ?s foaf:knows ?o
          }
      } OPTION (TRANSITIVE, t_distinct, t_in(?s), t_out(?o), t_min (1), t_max (4), t_step ('step_no') AS ?dist) .
      FILTER (?s= <http://www.w3.org/People/Berners-Lee/card#i>)
      FILTER (isIRI(?s) and isIRI(?o))
    }
  ORDER BY ?dist DESC (?contact_network_size)
  LIMIT 500
```

Note: this approach is the only way (at the current time) to expose actual relational hops between entities in an Entity Relationship Graph that includes Transitive relations.

> [image: screencap of results page]

- Live Link to [Query Results](http://linkeddata.uriburner.com/sparql?default-graph-uri=&query=SELECT%20%3Fo%20as%20%3FWebID%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%28%28SELECT%20COUNT%20%28*%29%20WHERE%20%7B%3Fo%20foaf%3Aknows%20%3Fxx%7D%29%29%20as%20%3Fcontact_network_size%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%3Fdist%20as%20%3FDegreeOfSeparation%20%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%3Chttp%3A%2F%2Fwww.w3.org%2FPeople%2FBerners-Lee%2Fcard%23i%3E%20as%20%3Fknowee%0D%0A%20%20WHERE%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20SELECT%20%3Fs%20%3Fo%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20WHERE%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%3Fs%20foaf%3Aknows%20%3Fo%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%7D%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%7D%20OPTION%20%28TRANSITIVE%2C%20t_distinct%2C%20t_in%28%3Fs%29%2C%20t_out%28%3Fo%29%2C%20t_min%20%281%29%2C%20t_max%20%284%29%2C%20t_step%20%28%27step_no%27%29%20as%20%3Fdist%29%20.%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20FILTER%20%28%3Fs%3D%20%3Chttp%3A%2F%2Fwww.w3.org%2FPeople%2FBerners-Lee%2Fcard%23i%3E%29%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20FILTER%20%28isIRI%28%3Fs%29%20and%20isIRI%28%3Fo%29%29%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%7D%0D%0A%20%20ORDER%20BY%20%3Fdist%20DESC%20%28%3Fcontact_network_size%29%0D%0A%20%20LIMIT%20500&should-sponge=&format=text%2Fx-html%2Btr&CXML_redir_for_subjs=121&CXML_redir_for_hrefs=&timeout=30000000)
- Live Link to [Query Source Code](http://linkeddata.uriburner.com/sparql?default-graph-uri=&qtxt=SELECT%20%3Fo%20as%20%3FWebID%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%28%28SELECT%20COUNT%20%28*%29%20WHERE%20%7B%3Fo%20foaf%3Aknows%20%3Fxx%7D%29%29%20as%20%3Fcontact_network_size%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%3Fdist%20as%20%3FDegreeOfSeparation%20%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%3Chttp%3A%2F%2Fwww.w3.org%2FPeople%2FBerners-Lee%2Fcard%23i%3E%20as%20%3Fknowee%0D%0A%20%20WHERE%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20SELECT%20%3Fs%20%3Fo%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20WHERE%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%3Fs%20foaf%3Aknows%20%3Fo%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%7D%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%7D%20OPTION%20%28TRANSITIVE%2C%20t_distinct%2C%20t_in%28%3Fs%29%2C%20t_out%28%3Fo%29%2C%20t_min%20%281%29%2C%20t_max%20%284%29%2C%20t_step%20%28%27step_no%27%29%20as%20%3Fdist%29%20.%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20FILTER%20%28%3Fs%3D%20%3Chttp%3A%2F%2Fwww.w3.org%2FPeople%2FBerners-Lee%2Fcard%23i%3E%29%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20FILTER%20%28isIRI%28%3Fs%29%20and%20isIRI%28%3Fo%29%29%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%7D%0D%0A%20%20ORDER%20BY%20%3Fdist%20DESC%20%28%3Fcontact_network_size%29%0D%0A%20%20LIMIT%20500&should-sponge=&format=text%2Fx-html%2Btr&CXML_redir_for_subjs=121&CXML_redir_for_hrefs=&timeout=30000000)