# Path queries in Wikidata endpoint?

Tags: sparql, wikidata

Consider the following snippet

```
ASK WHERE { wd:Q734774 wdt:P31 wd:Q3918. }
```

This [works fine in Wikidata](https://query.wikidata.org/#ASK%20WHERE%20%7B%20wd%3AQ734774%20wdt%3AP31%20wd%3AQ3918.%20%7D). I want to use some of the [path syntax](https://www.w3.org/TR/sparql11-property-paths/) in the this snippet. Specifically I want to limit the number of the times "wdt:P31" used in the path. According to the guidelines this should be the right syntax:

```
ASK WHERE { wd:Q734774 wdt:P31{,3} wd:Q3918. }
```

But it's giving me [weird error messages](https://query.wikidata.org/#ASK%20WHERE%20%7B%20wd%3AQ734774%20wdt%3AP31%7B%2C3%7D%20wd%3AQ3918.%20%7D). Any ideas?

Comment: The query is right; it (the same format) works in DBPedia. Perhaps some issue with the parser on wikidata?

Comment: No, you're wrong. You read a draft (from 2010) of the property path syntax. The restriction of the length of a property path did not make it to the final version (which was 3 years later): https://www.w3.org/TR/sparql11-query/#propertypaths

Comment: @AKSW I see ... then how can I simulate such behavior? (other than querying multiple times, and once for fixed path length, obviously)

Comment: You can't  really do it efficiently via SPARQL. That's the limitation of property paths. As you said, the only way would be to build the query by hand. Another option would be to compute the path length directly in the SPARQL query as suggested by JohuaTaylor here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5198889/calculate-length-of-path-between-nodes But this might not scale to big resp. deep graphs.

Comment: @AKSW - Not quite correct... See my answer.

Comment: You're right, sorry. I'll delete my comment

Answer (score 6):

The [final version of SPARQL 1.1 Property Paths](https://www.w3.org/TR/sparql11-query/#propertypaths) lets you do this with [the following query](https://query.wikidata.org/#ASK%20WHERE%20%0A%20%20%7B%20wd%3AQ734774%20%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20wdt%3AP31%3F%20%2F%20wdt%3AP31%3F%20%2F%20wdt%3AP31%3F%20%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20wd%3AQ3918%20%0A%20%20%7D) --

```
ASK WHERE 
  { wd:Q734774 
       wdt:P31? / wdt:P31? / wdt:P31? 
          wd:Q3918 
  }
```

For clarity, I've put the full *Property Path Predicate* (`wdt:P31? / wdt:P31? / wdt:P31?`) on a separate line between *Subject* (`wd:Q734774`) and *Object* (`wd:Q3918`).  The trailing `?` asks for one-or-zero instances of the `wdt:P31` predicate, and the `/` asks for a sequence, so this full path asks for a sequence of zero-or-one-or-two-or-three instances.

Comment: Thanks @TallTed for the answer. One question though. Suppose `ASK WHERE { wd:Q734774 wdt:P31* wd:Q3918. }`returns true. How can I query the length of the path which connects the two entities `wd:Q3918` and `wd:Q734774` together?

Comment: That's a very different question, and requires [a very different answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/41121465/241164).